# I need to create a selector in playwright way to locate second div adjacent to a selected locator

Tags: playwright, playwright-test, gui-testing

**What I want to do** : In playwright I want to click on the second div(having text "*click me*").

```
<div>
 <span>Algorithm</span>
 <div>Some div 1</div>
 <div>click me<div>
</div>
```

**What I have done** : `await page.getByText("Algorithm").first().locator("+ div + div").click();`
This fails as playwright is unable to locate.
**Note** : There are more than two span having "*Algorithm*" as text so using `first()`. Also the locator works fine till here `await page.getByText("Algorithm").first()`.

**What I want to achieve** : need help in modifying the above so that the target div having "*click me*" value is selected. I don't want to do `await page.getByText("click me")` but I want to follow the way of adjacent sibling locator as I am trying in my failed attempt.

Any help/guidance highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Bit hard to say without seeing rest of your page/elements, but you could give these a go:

Xpath

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Algorithm')]//following-sibling::div[contains(text(), 'click me')]
```

Playwright [positional locators](https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#css-matching-elements-based-on-layout)

```
div:text-is("click me"):below(:text-is("Algorithm"))
```

Comment: This is a useful answer in one of my scenarios!

Answer (score 0):

Also try this one code: `await page.locator(div:has(> span:has-text("Algorithm"))).first().locator("div").nth(1).click();`